# Is it possible to write an Excel Pivot Table object from pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pivot-table

I'm replacing a lot of my Excel workload with pandas. I need to generate a standard Excel Pivot Table object (with the interactive UI such that users can define filters as they see fit). I'm not too well versed in pandas.pivot_table(), but before digging in want to know if this is possible.
For example, given this DataFrame:

```
   Name Birth Year  Favorite Color
George  1987    Red
Maria   1987    Orange
Andrew  1992    Blue
Wyatt   1994    Red
Celeste 1987    Blue
Peter   1992    Blue
```

Is it possible to write an XLSX such as in this screenshot:

[image: Excel pivot table]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `df['favorite_color'].value_counts()`?

Comment: @QuangHoang Indeed, that'll get me the the same values, but I'm specifically looking for a way to write an Excel pivot table (as in the screenshot) into an XLSX from pandas/python. The important thing is that the UI of such a pivot table is interactive, and the end users can filter as they need.

Answer (score 1):

A user interface could easily be built for a pivot table.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'name': ['George', 'Maria', 'Andrew', 'Wyatt', 'Celeste', 'Peter'],
        'year': [1987, 1987, 1992, 1994, 1987, 1992],
        'color': ['Red', 'Orange', 'Blue', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Blue']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Simple interactive UI variable selection:
yr_selected = 'All'
if yr_selected != 'All':
    df = df.loc[df['year'] == yr_selected]
lbl_selected = 'color'

pt = df.pivot_table(index=[lbl_selected], values=['name'], aggfunc='count', margins=True)

print(pt)
```

Output:

```
        name
color
Blue       3
Orange     1
Red        2
All        6
```

Comment: Thanks, and yes that is a good way that I would go about getting the information for myself, but I need to present this in the format that is currently accepted by my colleagues, an Excel pivot table in an XLSX sheet. Previously this had been generated manually in Excel, and I'm trying to reduce that effort.

Comment: Your goal is not clear to me. My understanding was that you are trying to replace Excel with Python. Now, I'm understanding that your users will still be using Excel for this pivot table task. If you want to keep using the Excel pivot table object, why not write a VBA macro to generate that object rather than manually creating it? You can also use pywin32 to generate an Excel object from python. Pandas can not create an Excel object (which is exactly what you asked in the title).

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. I should have been more clear - I'm replacing the work that I had previously done in Excel - data validation, vlookups, etc, with Python and pandas. My output from this is still to write an XLSX in order to not alter my team's workflow. I will investigate other options, specifically VBA, to create the Pivot Table.

Comment: With a VBA macro, depending on your project, you might not have to do any routine work. They open up the Excel file and it's done. The macro can run on opening, they can push a button or select a command that is located in the Excel menu.